# What is the difference between "trackDisabled" and "trackRemoved" events in twilio-video?

Tags: video, twilio, twilio-api

What is the differnce between the trackDisabled and trackRemoved events in the twilio javascript SDK? Is disabling a track equivalent to removing it? Whats the difference exactly?

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant to say trackRemoved and trackDisabled. Edited for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is that disabling it means something like pausing and removing it means scrapping it for good. 
If you disable it, it is still there, just not sending any video/audio/media data. If you remove it, if you want to send video/audio/media data again, you have to create a new track and to tell twilio it can use it in the current conversation in order for it to be able to distribute your data to the other participants in the room.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. That is spot on!